# How to make a textbox behave like a dropdownlist using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am facing some problem. I want to make a `textbox` behave like a `dropdownlist` while the `textbox` still remains editable. I want the text that will have data populated from a database (like google search always shows some hints once we start writing). How can I approach this?

Comment: you really got to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean an auto-filler?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

The link above should provide all the answers you need. You can use this method in conjuction with ajax to give you a list based on the current value. Comment if you need more detail.